# How to prevent HDMI cable from coming loose

Tags: cables

I currently have my laptop hooked up to an LG 22LS4D TV screen which I use for programming. The problem is, whenever the HDMI cable is moved slightly (such as when the curtains behind are opened/closed or when the lead is accidentally pulled), the cable disconnects from the TV so I do not have an input.

**How would I be able to make sure my HDMI cable disconnect less often?**.

Also while we are on the same topic, it is also hard to reconnect since I have to reach behind the TV and the cable/port is loose so it takes multiple attempts to connect. **How would I be able to connect the cable easier?**

Comment: Have you tried anything to help keep it in place at this point? If you have, edit your answer and included those attempts first.

Comment: I have a hard time believing a HDMI cable unplugs easily, the connection is usually super sturdy.

Comment: @JustDoIt I think its the build quality or the port is not that good. The cable wiggles about a lot and is hard to get it into a position where it gets signal,

Comment: Agree with L.B. - please edit question to reflect what you have tried that has not worked.

Comment: @Ceylon_17 This is not something I can show easily. Some I am not doing because they cost money, others it won't show well on the picture due to the amount it would be out by.

Comment: There are an amazing variety of great tips in this question which help me in a similar “low build quality” hdmi port problem. Very grateful for the original post. Angle joints, screwlock, and even the idea of reversing the cable direction are all great for me. My own problem is worse than the OP. When my TV heats up, it doesn’t need a rustling curtain to disconnect— it does it on its own. I wish someone manufactured a hdmi plug that was advertised as “extra snug fit” to occupy a too-loose jack firmly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way how I have fixed the problem is to use blue tack.

What I done was wrap blue tack around the HDMI cable so it was sticking out slightly, after that I then pushed the HDMI into the TV port and smoothed it around. Once it was in, I added more blue tack over until it looked like this:

[image]

The reason why I have not used your suggestions is because they either don't work (for example making a **U** or **L** knot doesn't work because how thick and heavy the cable is), or the options cost money.

This bodge repair works for me because it makes the connection more secure while costing nothing (already had blue tack laying around) and it was able to make it harder to pull out.

Answer (score 5):

This is an adaptation of my own answer on Ask Different, for a similar circumstance.

One way to alleviate the pulling action is to try to get the cable pointing in a better natural direction between your two end points.

You can turn any cable into an approximation of an **L** or even a **U** by the simple expedient of tying a knot in it.

This is my standard way of dealing with any awkward cable.
It's not perfect, but boy, it's cheap ;-)

**L-knot**

[image]

**U-knot**

[image]

The U-knot is achieved by simply wrapping one end through a second time, if it's not clear from the picture.

BTW - keep the knot very loose, so you don't damage anything.

Of course, no knot is going to help if the cable gets yanked, in any direction;  this idea is really just to set the cable off in the right direction, it will not work miracles.
Just reducing its tendency to want to be straighter in the 'wrong' direction, nothing more, & reducing pull angularly, thereby reducing the lever length of the cable in that one direction.

Comment: This does not work for me since the cable is too heavy (which is why it easily falls out)

Comment: The L knot is also (usually?) known as a thumb knot or overhand knot. The U knot as a double of the same.

Answer (score 3):

I find a (very) small drop of Screwlock will hold a plug in place.

Screwlock is intended to stop screws coming loose in applications where they are subject to a lot of flexing, such as those that hold the arms onto the frames of spectacles.  It is not permanent, so when you want to remove the screw, it is easy.

The same applies to your plug.  A drop on the plug frame helps to hold it in the socket.  But a deliberate pull on the plug will remove it.

This should survive your pulling the curtains if you don't knock the cable too heavily.

Screwlock (otherwise known as Loctite 222) is available from any decent hardware shop.  There are probably competing products with similar names.

Answer (score 2):

Get a HDMI extension, connect one end to the back of the TV, securing it with black tape so it won't disconnect easily, and stick the other end firmly to an easily reachable part of the TV, such as it's base, the desk or even the wall.

[image: HDMI Extension]

This way you are basically bringing the socket from the back of the TV (which is hard to reach) to an easier to reach point.

A HDMI Angle Joint can be of big help to secure the cable on TV's back!

[image: HDMI angle joint]

Comment: The right-angle HDMI adapter will work.

Answer (score 1):

Making it easier to reconnect doesn't solve the problem. If you really want it more accessible, a wall mount that swivels out is the best option.

Things to try (order on cost and simplicity) to solve the real problem.

1. Try a different HDMI port on the display (maybe that one is simply out of spec)
2. Flip the cable so the display end now connects to your computer and vice-versa
3. Wrap the cable around the power cable a couple of times loosely
4. Tape or zip-tie the HDMI cable to the power cable